# JPA aggregate root approach

Tags: java, jpa, aggregateroot

I'll use a blog post as an example.

The `BlogPost` entity is an aggregate root, and it contains a `BlogPostComment` collection.
That's good because a post comment cannot exist without a parent blog post. Every operation on a `BlogPostComment` is taken care of by a `BlogPost`, or better by the service which manages `BlogPost` entities.

However, by taking this route, every time I want to add a comment, I'm forced to retrieve all the blog post information. Every time I want to remove a comment, I'm forced to retrieve all the blog post information. Etc.

So the first and most obvious solution would be to offer a separate service to operate on `BlogPostComment`(s). But that would violate the concept of a post comment. You shouldn't be able to operate on comments alone.

What's the right way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's acceptable to split comments from articles as there could be a huge number of comments. If comments can be organised/rendered as threads then a thread might be a good aggregate root. A thread can then do things like compute the nested depth of comments to assist in rendering. That logic can then be in the ”smallest scope” of the thread and not part of the article object logic.

Such things are design decisions. They may change as the model evolves. Breaking up the model into manageable pieces that can be worked with efficiently is a matter of working with the code and refactoring it when it becomes unwieldy

Comment: You are welcome. Eager loading of comments with blog articles is always going to be a bad idea for performance. I am also thinking that rendered comment threads with pagination is going to need a custom query (possibly using `select new`). Blogs aren't a very good example of where DDD is a very strong fit as the business rules are very simple, the rendering is very bespoke, and there are not multiple workflows interacting with it. DDD should shine when an app needs the business logic to be refactored to add logic and where there are multiple workflows that use the model.

Comment: Yeah I took the blog example only because everyone know how it usually works.

Comment: Just in case anyone is interested in a blog series on jpa and ddd here is one I wrote https://simbo1905.blog/2016/07/18/domain-driven-design-entities-value-objects-aggregates-and-roots-with-jpa-part-1/

Comment: Sorry I forgot to comment with the link.